# side caption on beamer poster

Tags: beamer, beamerposter, sidecap

I like to write caption on the side of the image in a poster using Beamer.
I write something like the below. But it doesnt work. It show me  a error message:

```
texify.exe: Windows API error 32: The process cannot access
the file because it is being used by another process.

texify.exe: Data: 1.log
```

Could any one tell me, how to solve this problem?

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage[margincaption]{sidecap}

\begin{document}

\begin{textblock}{}[0,-2.5](33cm,0cm)%
\begin{varblock}[43cm]{}

\begin{SCfigure}
  \centering
\includegraphics[height=10cm]{Figure/Panorama_LB.jpg} 
  \caption{ ... caption text ... }
\end{SCfigure}
\end{varblock}
\end{textblock}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example can't be compile. The environment `textblock` and `varblock` are undefined.

Comment: What's the connection with beamerposter?

Comment: @Marco Daniel:I did, as the script is quite long I mention some of Them. I defined varblock by                                      \newenvironment<>{varblock}[2][\textwidth]{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{#1}
  \begin{actionenv}#3%
    \def\insertblocktitle{#2}%
    \par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
  {\par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block end}%
  \end{actionenv}}                                               every thing works great, only when I use SCfigure it script cant compile.